# Using pdflatex.exe to Convert TeX to PDF within a C#

Tags: errors, compiling

I have my TeX file (only `firstExample.tex` inside my folder) document and I want to convert it to PDF and display it within the application.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
this is only a test
$$(x+1)$$
\end{document}
```

i do this:

```
 string filename = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Application\Temp\firstExample.tex";
                Process p1 = new Process();
                p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe";
                p1.StartInfo.Arguments = filename;
                p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                p1.Start();
                var output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p1.WaitForExit();
```

but output returns :

```
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode !
I can't write on file `firstExample.log'
Please type another transcript file name: "
```

instead of the expected PDF

Comment: I suspect this is more suited on StackOverflow. That question is due to some problem of how C calls the command. I don't suspect it has anything to do with TeX.

Comment: Completely unrelated note: Don't use `$$ .. $$`, see e.g. [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503))

Comment: A few thoughts, without knowing (much) C#:  Where is it trying to create the log, and do you have write permissions there (what windows version).  So try making sure you're starting from the folder containing the .tex file.  btw you should omit the `.tex` extension when running (pdf)latex.

Comment: Ok, but when i run pdflatex.exe manually and write the path to my tex file [link](http://prikachi.com/images/398/6815398Q.png) with text <code>
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
this is only a test
\end{document} </code>
I think its not working properly on pdflatex.exe? 
Is it possible to show me a working example that returns PDF from pdflatex.exe?

Comment: The code you wrote there (and in the question, for that matter) will both provide a PDF when compiled with `pdflatex`. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been tested and it works as expected.

### Step 1: Create a batch file

To avoid recompiling the C# source code to be in sync with the (La)TeX compiler you want to use, it will be convenient to create a batch file. The batch file executes (La)TeX compiler behind the scene. Save the batch file anywhere and set the PATH system variable to the batch location. But for the sake of simplicity, you can save it in a directory in which the LaTeX input file exists.

The simplest batch may be as follows

```
rem batch.bat
rem %1 represents the file name with no extension.
pdflatex -shell-escape %1
```

### Step 2: Create the C# code and compile

The simplest example is as follows:

```cs
   using System.Diagnostics;
   class MyApp
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = "batch.bat";
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p1.Start();
            p1.WaitForExit();
         }
     }
```

Compile it with C# compiler to get `MyApp.exe` for example. Save it in a specific directory and set `PATH` system variable to point it. But for the sake of simplicity, you can save it a directory in which the LaTeX input file exists.

### Step 3: Create a test LaTeX input file

Create and save the following LaTeX input file in a directory that has read and write permission.

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

### Step 4: Make a try

`MyApp.exe` needs a single argument which is the TeX input file name with no extension.

From command prompt, you execute `MyApp.exe test`.

### Step 5: Vote this answer up!

Comment: It is taken from [my another answer here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53918/19356).

Answer (score 1):

This would be a reply to the OP's comment, but for the need for formatting (and probably length).

Create a file containing the following, call it `hw.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

from the command line, in the folder where that file is saved, type `pdflatex hw`.  Does it work?

then move `hw.tex` to `c:\`, and run `pdflatex c:/hw`.  That really is a **forward slash** even on windows.  That may in fact be your error.

Comment: ok i will try this :)