# I want to compile a pdf document using latex as part of a java program

Tags: java

I'm doing a java project and want to produce a word doc or pdf of inputted (formatted) text. I've read that I could use Apache POI xwpf, but I know infinitely more LaTEx commands than apache poi. How would I get my java program to open miketex and compile a tex file?

Comment: I think this would be better suited to stackoverflow.com, but the way I do it is to run `pdflatex` (or whatever format is required) using a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: You should be able to find a similar approach in Java once you read [Invoking LaTeX compiler programmatically with c#](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53914/87876).

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea about java, but surely you can run a software installed on the system. How to invoke pdftex: read the pdfTEX user manual, section 4, please. If you have a working installation of MiKTEX or texlive, type `texdoc pdftex-a` on the command line. Otherwise see here: https://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex

By the way, people usually use LaTeX. So if you are unsure, show us a minimal working example of a *.tex file you would like to compile.